# Use a mapping dataframe to replace values in several columns of pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 data frames.
One is data that has codes in the fields. I want to map these codes to values.
The other is a data frame that has the code and mapped value for each column in a long format.
Here is an example:

The main data frame `data` with codes:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    1|    C|    2|   90|
|    1|    F|    1|    8|
|    2|    D|  999|   10|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

The long-format mapping data frame `mapping`:

```
+-----+----+------+
|field|code| value|
+-----+----+------+
|col_1|   1|  True|
|col_1|   2| False|
|col_2|   C|   Cat|
|col_2|   D|   Dog|
|col_2|   F|  Fish|
|col_3|   1| Adult|
|col_3|   2| Child|
|col_3|   3|Infant|
|col_3| 999|    NA|
+-----+----+------+
```

The result I want is:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| True|  Cat|Child|   90|
| True| Fish|Adult|    8|
|False|  Dog|   NA|   10|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want the best/cleanest/fastest way to do it in pySpark.
This is what I have but it seems rather clunky:

```
map_cols = [x.field for x in mapping.select("field").distinct().collect()]
for mc in map_cols:
    sub_map_df = mapping.filter(f"field == '{mc}'")
    sub_map = {x.code: x.value for x in sub_map_df.collect()}
    data = data.replace(sub_map, subset=[mc])
```

In pandas, this is easy. This is my favorite way of doing it:

```
m = {x: y.set_index("code")["value"].to_dict() for x, y in mapping.groupby("field")}
data.replace(m, inplace=True)
```

PySpark doesn't have nested dictionaries as an option for the `to_replace` value in its `.replace()` function and weird security measures on the Azure DataBricks cluster prevent me from using `.toPandas()`.

So my question is this:
**Is there a better way to do this problem?**
My solution seems confusing, hard to read, and rather un-pythonic. It also might be slow because we're looping over every column (but that one I don't know for sure).

Thanks!

Comment: Did the proposed answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I would recommend is doing it all in spark. You could achieve this using spark sql using left joins, case expressions and broadcasting the mapping dataframe to make it more efficient.

I've included an example below.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data_codes.createOrReplaceTempView("data_codes")
F.broadcast(mapping_data).createOrReplaceTempView("mapping_data")

result_df = sparkSession.sql("""
    SELECT
       CASE 
           WHEN mdc1.value IS NOT NULL THEN mdc1.value
           ELSE dc.col_1 
       END as col1,
       CASE 
           WHEN mdc2.value IS NOT NULL THEN mdc2.value
           ELSE dc.col_2 
       END as col2,
       CASE 
           WHEN mdc3.value IS NOT NULL THEN mdc3.value
           ELSE dc.col_3 
       END as col3,
       CASE 
           WHEN mdc4.value IS NOT NULL THEN mdc4.value
           ELSE dc.col_4 
       END as col4
    FROM
        data_codes dc
    LEFT JOIN
        mapping_data mdc1 ON mdc1.field='col_1' and mdc1.code=dc.col_1
    LEFT JOIN
        mapping_data mdc2 ON mdc2.field='col_2' and mdc2.code=dc.col_2
    LEFT JOIN
        mapping_data mdc3 ON mdc3.field='col_3' and mdc3.code=dc.col_3
    LEFT JOIN
        mapping_data mdc4 ON mdc4.field='col_4' and mdc4.code=dc.col_4
""")

result_df.show()
```

Outputs

```
+-----+----+-----+----+
| col1|col2| col3|col4|
+-----+----+-----+----+
| True| Cat|Child|  90|
| True|Fish|Adult|   8|
|False| Dog|   NA|  10|
+-----+----+-----+----+
```

A few observations to note with this approach.

1. I've created temporary views of the dataframes so that I may access each in spark sql. Spark will scale the solution accordingly to how many nodes/partitions you have.
2. I am using a LEFT JOIN along with CASE expressions. The left join will match in your mapping data if it does find a mapping. The case expression will check if the mapping value is NULL before using that value or reverting back to the original value.
3. I am broadcasting the `mapping_data` data frame. I've chosen to do this on the assumption that your mapping_data is relatively small and can fit on each of your executor nodes. Also it is important to note that whenever spark does a join it will most likely shuffle the data across nodes which can be expensive at times. The broadcast ensures that there is a copy of the mapping data on all nodes thereby reducing the number of shuffles and improving your execution.

I've included both execution plans (you can use the `explain` on a dataframe to achieve this)

Without the broadcast:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(17) Project [CASE WHEN isnotnull(value#27) THEN value#27 ELSE col_1#0 END AS col1#199, CASE WHEN isnotnull(value#205) THEN value#205 ELSE col_2#1 END AS col2#200, CASE WHEN isnotnull(value#208) THEN value#208 ELSE col_3#2 END AS col3#201, CASE WHEN isnotnull(value#211) THEN value#211 ELSE col_4#3 END AS col4#202]
+- SortMergeJoin [col_4#3], [code#210], LeftOuter, (field#25 = col_4)
   :- *(14) Sort [col_4#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_4#3, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#575]
   :     +- *(13) Project [col_1#0, col_2#1, col_3#2, col_4#3, field#25, value#27, value#205, value#208]
   :        +- SortMergeJoin [col_3#2], [code#207], LeftOuter, (field#25 = col_3)
   :           :- *(10) Sort [col_3#2 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_3#2, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#525]
   :           :     +- *(9) Project [col_1#0, col_2#1, col_3#2, col_4#3, field#25, value#27, value#205]
   :           :        +- SortMergeJoin [col_2#1], [code#204], LeftOuter, (field#25 = col_2)
   :           :           :- *(6) Sort [col_2#1 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :           :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_2#1, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#512]
   :           :           :     +- *(5) Project [col_1#0, col_2#1, col_3#2, col_4#3, field#25, value#27]
   :           :           :        +- SortMergeJoin [col_1#0], [code#26], LeftOuter
   :           :           :           :- *(2) Sort [col_1#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :           :           :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#0, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#499]
   :           :           :           :     +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#0,col_2#1,col_3#2,col_4#3]
   :           :           :           +- *(4) Sort [code#26 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :           :           :              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(code#26, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#504]
   :           :           :                 +- *(3) Filter ((isnotnull(field#25) AND (field#25 = col_1)) AND isnotnull(code#26))
   :           :           :                    +- *(3) Scan ExistingRDD[field#25,code#26,value#27]
   :           :           +- *(8) Sort [code#204 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :           :              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(code#204, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#517]
   :           :                 +- *(7) Project [code#204, value#205]
   :           :                    +- *(7) Filter isnotnull(code#204)
   :           :                       +- *(7) Scan ExistingRDD[field#203,code#204,value#205]
   :           +- *(12) Sort [code#207 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :              +- ReusedExchange [code#207, value#208], Exchange hashpartitioning(code#204, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#517]
   +- *(16) Sort [code#210 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- ReusedExchange [code#210, value#211], Exchange hashpartitioning(code#204, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#517]
```

With the broadcast:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) Project [CASE WHEN isnotnull(value#27) THEN value#27 ELSE col_1#0 END AS col1#216, CASE WHEN isnotnull(value#222) THEN value#222 ELSE col_2#1 END AS col2#217, CASE WHEN isnotnull(value#225) THEN value#225 ELSE col_3#2 END AS col3#218, CASE WHEN isnotnull(value#228) THEN value#228 ELSE col_4#3 END AS col4#219]
+- *(5) BroadcastHashJoin [col_4#3], [code#227], LeftOuter, BuildRight, (field#25 = col_4), false
   :- *(5) Project [col_1#0, col_2#1, col_3#2, col_4#3, field#25, value#27, value#222, value#225]
   :  +- *(5) BroadcastHashJoin [col_3#2], [code#224], LeftOuter, BuildRight, (field#25 = col_3), false
   :     :- *(5) Project [col_1#0, col_2#1, col_3#2, col_4#3, field#25, value#27, value#222]
   :     :  +- *(5) BroadcastHashJoin [col_2#1], [code#221], LeftOuter, BuildRight, (field#25 = col_2), false
   :     :     :- *(5) Project [col_1#0, col_2#1, col_3#2, col_4#3, field#25, value#27]
   :     :     :  +- *(5) BroadcastHashJoin [col_1#0], [code#26], LeftOuter, BuildRight, false
   :     :     :     :- *(5) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#0,col_2#1,col_3#2,col_4#3]
   :     :     :     +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[1, string, false]),false), [id=#696]
   :     :     :        +- *(1) Filter ((isnotnull(field#25) AND (field#25 = col_1)) AND isnotnull(code#26))
   :     :     :           +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[field#25,code#26,value#27]
   :     :     +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]),false), [id=#701]
   :     :        +- *(2) Project [code#221, value#222]
   :     :           +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(code#221)
   :     :              +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[field#220,code#221,value#222]
   :     +- ReusedExchange [code#224, value#225], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]),false), [id=#701]
   +- ReusedExchange [code#227, value#228], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]),false), [id=#701]
```

4. I am assuming this is sample data. Thank you for providing such for the question. This has been really helpful in providing an answer which I hope you find helpful. However, if your sample schema is similar to what you shared in this question, i.e. `col_1`, `col_2` then it is possible to generate this `sql` query using python.

Eg.

```py
case_expressions=""
join_clauses=""
no_cols=4
for col_num in range(1,no_cols+1):
    case_expressions = case_expressions + ("" if col_num == 1 else ",")+"""
       CASE 
           WHEN mdc{0}.value IS NOT NULL THEN mdc{0}.value
           ELSE dc.col_{0} 
       END as col{0}
    """.format(col_num)
    join_clauses = join_clauses + """
    LEFT JOIN
        mapping_data mdc{0} ON mdc{0}.field='col_{0}' and mdc{0}.code=dc.col_{0}
    """.format(col_num)

combined_sql="""
SELECT
       {0}
    FROM
        data_codes dc
    {1}
""".format(case_expressions,join_clauses)
```

Let me know if this helps.